# Converting a JSON file to a workable dataframe in R

Tags: r, json

I've searched through many solutions here but can't get exactly what I'm looking for in this situation.

I pull a JSON file from an API and get as far as get it into a list. The data is basically a list of values for a day in 5 minute intervals. The values are in a list of length 288 (as there are 288 5 minute intervals in a day) and there is a startTime object that starts at date-00:00:00 and then another of intervalLength '00:05:00' but these are not lists.

```
> dput(jdf)
list(startTime = "2021-11-07T00:00:00.000+00:00", intervalLength = "00:05:00", 
    values = list(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7.66666666666667, 
        7.66666666666667, 7.66666666666667, 16L, 16L, 16L, 28.3333333333333, 
        28.3333333333333, 28.3333333333333, 25.3333333333333, 
        25.3333333333333, 25.3333333333333, 36.6666666666667, 
        36.6666666666667, 36.6666666666667, 48.3333333333333, 
        48.3333333333333, 48.3333333333333, 45.3333333333333, 
        45.3333333333333, 45.3333333333333, 56.3333333333333, 
        56.3333333333333, 56.3333333333333, 57.6666666666667, 
        57.6666666666667, 57.6666666666667, 54.6666666666667, 
        54.6666666666667, 54.6666666666667, 62.6666666666667, 
        62.6666666666667, 62.6666666666667, 73.3333333333333, 
        73.3333333333333, 73.3333333333333, 79.3333333333333, 
        79.3333333333333, 79.3333333333333, 81.6666666666667, 
        81.6666666666667, 81.6666666666667, 85L, 85L, 85L, 99L, 
        99L, 99L, 92.3333333333333, 92.3333333333333, 92.3333333333333, 
        110L, 110L, 110L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 
        126.333333333333, 126.333333333333, 126.333333333333, 
        123.666666666667, 123.666666666667, 123.666666666667, 
        123L, 123L, 123L, 122.333333333333, 122.333333333333, 
        122.333333333333, 118.333333333333, 118.333333333333, 
        118.333333333333, 99L, 99L, 99L, 89.6666666666667, 89.6666666666667, 
        89.6666666666667, 79.6666666666667, 79.6666666666667, 
        79.6666666666667, 86L, 86L, 86L, 91.3333333333333, 91.3333333333333, 
        91.3333333333333, 99.3333333333333, 99.3333333333333, 
        99.3333333333333, 120L, 120L, 120L, 114.666666666667, 
        114.666666666667, 114.666666666667, 119.666666666667, 
        119.666666666667, 119.666666666667, 112.333333333333, 
        112.333333333333, 112.333333333333, 90.3333333333333, 
        90.3333333333333, 90.3333333333333, 81.3333333333333, 
        81.3333333333333, 81.3333333333333, 67.6666666666667, 
        67.6666666666667, 67.6666666666667, 67.6666666666667, 
        67.6666666666667, 67.6666666666667, 66L, 66L, 66L, 75L, 
        75L, 75L, 82.6666666666667, 82.6666666666667, 82.6666666666667, 
        80L, 80L, 80L, 81.3333333333333, 81.3333333333333, 81.3333333333333, 
        76.6666666666667, 76.6666666666667, 76.6666666666667, 
        67.3333333333333, 67.3333333333333, 67.3333333333333, 
        65.6666666666667, 65.6666666666667, 65.6666666666667, 
        57.3333333333333, 57.3333333333333, 57.3333333333333, 
        71.3333333333333, 71.3333333333333, 71.3333333333333, 
        84.3333333333333, 84.3333333333333, 84.3333333333333, 
        91L, 91L, 91L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 109.666666666667, 109.666666666667, 
        109.666666666667, 105L, 105L, 105L, 117.666666666667, 
        117.666666666667, 117.666666666667, 118L, 118L, 118L, 
        110.333333333333, 110.333333333333, 110.333333333333, 
        105L, 105L, 105L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 62.3333333333333, 
        62.3333333333333, 62.3333333333333, 48.3333333333333, 
        48.3333333333333, 48.3333333333333, 32.3333333333333, 
        32.3333333333333, 32.3333333333333, 21.3333333333333, 
        21.3333333333333, 21.3333333333333, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17.6666666666667, 
        17.6666666666667, 17.6666666666667, 14.3333333333333, 
        14.3333333333333, 14.3333333333333, 8.66666666666667, 
        8.66666666666667, 8.66666666666667, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1.33333333333333, 
        1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L))
```

To this

```
> glimpse(exampledate)
Rows: 288
Columns: 2
$ Time   <dttm> 2021-11-13 00:00:00, 2021-11-13 00:05:00, 2021-11-13 00:10:00, 2021-11-13 00:15:00, 2021-11-13 00:20:00, 2021-11-13 …
$ values <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi Ben. It's not clear what a concrete answer would look like here without a concrete working example. The structure of a JSON can be quite idiosyncratic, so anyone venturing an answer would need your actual input data (not a screenshot of the structure of the input data). Could you post the actual list object please? If it is called `myjson` then you would type `dput(myjson)` in your r console and paste the result (it will be long) into a code block in your question. You can declare a code block with three backticks on their own line.

Comment: Said a little more directly, Ben: I'm not going to spend time trying to transcribe your picture-of-data into something usable. Additionally, while I have the luxury of being able to see it, not everybody does, and images-of-code/data make it nearly impossible for screen-readers to give a good representation of your data/question. Your goal should be to make it as easy for us as possible to help you. (See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/).)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback both I will try and reshape the ask in the original post

Comment: Looking at your data it seems things are happening on a 15-min level, not sure if you want to reduce your dataset to that level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rrapply)
library(lubridate)

start <- as_datetime(jdf[[1]])
interval <- seconds(hms(jdf[[2]]))

jdf %>%
  rrapply(., how = 'melt') %>%
  slice(-c(1:2)) %>%
  mutate(Time = start,
         add = interval * (0:(n() - 1)),
         Time = Time + add) %>%
  select(-L1, -L2, -add)
```

The first 10 rows:

```
       value                Time
1          0 2021-11-07 00:00:00
2          0 2021-11-07 00:05:00
3          0 2021-11-07 00:10:00
4          0 2021-11-07 00:15:00
5          0 2021-11-07 00:20:00
6          0 2021-11-07 00:25:00
7          0 2021-11-07 00:30:00
8          0 2021-11-07 00:35:00
9          0 2021-11-07 00:40:00
10         0 2021-11-07 00:45:00
```

Comment: amazing thank you so much